# NodeList object's length property readonly, how to verify?

Tags: javascript

Property descriptor object of length property shows configurable: true, writable:true and enymerable:true but it behaves like read only.

I knew that readonly feature can only be implemented by PDO(property descriptor object).

Can someone give any clue?
How is this readonly?

```
var nodeList = document.getElementsByName('demo');

nodeList.length; //3
nodeList.length = 6;
nodeList.length; //3

Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(nodeList,'length')
Object
configurable: true
enumerable: true
value: 3
writable: true
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: DOM elements have a native implementation. It's possible that one restricts their behaviour above what Javascript's reflection metadata tells you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`length` is read-only, as per http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177

Indeed that display is misleading, but that's because it's a host object, so it doesn't have to behave like a native object like we're used to. That is worth a bug report though, since the display should match the behaviour as closely as possible, especially in obvious cases like this.

Comment: Exactly - seems to be a bug. Should vary with Javascript engine. Do we expect a different behaviour if tried in a different browser?

Comment: In Opera, it's a getter/setter property.

Answer (score 1):

The [DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#nodelist) defines `length` as readonly:

```
interface NodeList {
  getter Node? item(unsigned long index);
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
};
```

It may seem that `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` shouldn't say that it's writable. However, `NodeList` instances are [host objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.8):

> object supplied by the host environment to complete the execution
>   environment of ECMAScript

Therefore, they can have special behaviors. In fact, this one is enforced by [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2):

> If a property is described as a data property and it may return
>   different values over time, then either or both of the [[Writable]]
>   and [[Configurable]] attributes must be true even if no mechanism to
>   change the value is exposed via the other internal methods.

Since `getElementsByName` returns a live collection, `length` may change, so [[Writable]] or [Configurable]] must be `true`. Your implementation chooses both.